# How can I change the target framework in Visual studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, visual-studio-mac

I want to set the target framework in Visual Studio for Mac because of this problem:

> The referenced component 'xxxx' not found for framework .NET Framework
>   4.6.1

Comment: To clarify: Your company has it's own flavour of the .NET Framework?

Comment: My boss give me a url and tell me this is our framework package source.

Comment: 'xxxx' not found for framework .NET Framework 4.6.1 .All component with this problem are our own component.But some our component is ok.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough#adding-package-sources It is likely that your boss gave you a NuGet source URL, which you should configure as Microsoft documents. There is nothing called "my own framework" or "framework package source".

Comment: Sorry, I am fledgling.I have already configure them as Microsoft dobuments.Restored packages successfully but in folder called references,some package is wrong!

Comment: xxxx component could be built with another .NET framework version than that of your solution. Try finding the framework version of the DLL using File > Properties. If possible make your solution target same .NET framework. Your boss might have just given you a local Nuget copy

Comment: Thank you!I know why!Thank you forever!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by make my solution target same .NET framework.Because some component use .net core2.0 ,it is higher than others